# How do I make voice to text work in SE chat?

Tags: support, bug, user-interface, accessibility

As I recover from a hand injury, I attempted to use voice-to-text in RPG.SE chat. It did not work.  It did work in the upper room. (Christianity.SE chat).

It did work in the title to the question, but it did not work in the body of the question at RPG.SE.
It also does work in the comments under the questions and answers.  I am able to voice to text into this box for this question here.

The feature I am using is windows key + H (Windows 10). The question (at RPGSE) was posted by doing voice to text into notepad, and then copying and pasting into the question box, and then editing a bit.

Is there a toggle that needs to be switched on at RPG.SE?

Comment: I am not sure what to do now.  Perhaps somebody hit a switch or perhaps I miss hit something and didn't realise that the microphone or function was not working. It is now working in that chat.  If somebody fixed it, thank you 

Comment: Well, in that case, I put it on hold as 'can no longer be reproduced'. If you do encounter problems again, feel free to [edit] in the update and ping me to reopen :)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I have reason to believe that this is a [Windows-ism](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10020/22566)